# Take two nested for loops. How can I make a variable count further up, after jumping cycling the loops?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, nested-loops

I'm sure the answer is fairly simple, but I'm not getting it. Here we go with my example:

```
int matrix [][] = new int [rows][columns];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
        {
            mata[i][j] = Integer.parseInt (args[j]);
        }
    }
```

How can I make `j` count further upwards after the programm goes from the inner loop to the outer loop and back to the inner one? Usually, it would start from zero again, which is not intended, as I need the next command line argument. I tried a few things, can't get it to work, though.

Comment: Specify the language(s) you're using by adding the appropriate tag(s), and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `args` is the array of command-line arguments, you should really wrap invocations of [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) in a `try`-`catch`(-`finally`) construct, in order to handle a possible `NumberFormatException`. Don't simply rely on the user passing meaningful arguments.

Comment: It is a uni assignment, so I don't really have to worry about that. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an outer variable:

```
int k = 0;
```

then replace the innermost line by:

```
mata[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(args[k]);
k += 1;
```

Or compute it:

```
mata[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(args[i * matrix.length + j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a separate variable (`argc` below):

```
int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];

for (int i = 0, argc = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++, argc++) {
    mata[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(args[argc]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Complete aside - every time you put a space before the opening parenthesis of a function call, a puppy dies.

Comment: Sorry :/
I got it now, though. Thank you!